# JQuery Skips the Whole AJAX section

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't figure out why, when stepping through, it just skips right over the Ajax section calling a method in the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult findUser(userIdModel lookfor)
    {
        Citrix citrix = new Citrix();
        List<string[]> result = citrix.findUser(lookfor.username);
        FindUserModel model = new FindUserModel();
        result.ForEach(x => model.ServerName = x[1]);
        return Json(model);
    }
```

And

```
@Html.TextBox("strUser", "", new { id = "userid" })
<input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-default" id="lookup" />
<text id="results"></text>
<script>
    $('#lookup').click(function (event) {
        strUser = $('#userid').val();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "username":"' + strUser + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/findUser",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#results').val(data.servername)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's because you don't stop the submit button from submitting the parent form. Add `event.preventDefault()` to the click handler

Comment: Is there a `<form>` associated with this?  What do you mean it "skips" the AJAX call?  Is the form submitting normally instead of using AJAX?  Is the AJAX call being made *and* the form is submitting?  Is there no form at all?  If not, then what specifically is happening?  In your browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX call made at all on the network tab?  If you debug your server-side code, is that action invoked?  What *specifically* is happening here and how is it failing?

Comment: I can put a stop at the beginning of the script section, it steps down to ajax and then skips to the end. No the form is not submitting normally it's calling this jquery script instead.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle: Well, AJAX is *asynchronous*.  So the call to `$.ajax()` is itself a single operation.  In your browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Have you tried placing a break point in the server-side code to debug that?  Have you tried placing a break point in the `.done()` callback function to debug that?  So far the behavior you're describing is entirely correct and expected, so it's not clear what actual problem is being observed other than a potential misunderstanding on your part of how asynchronous operations work.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle: Also, regarding your edit, what on earth is a `<text>` element?  Is your browser even rendering that in any way?  In the `.done()` callback function when you attempt to select that element, does jQuery even find it?  It's entirely possible that you simply have invalid HTML here and the code is working fine but you don't have any valid output to display.

Comment: I don't know if that <text> element will work or not, I can't even get that far right now. The problem is that the ajax section doesn't even run and I have a break point in the controller section (server side) and it's not even getting there. I've seen this problem before but I don't remember what I did to fix it.

Comment: To answer your other question it gets to the done section but skips the post url and data parts.

Comment: I got it working but not sure how exactly. Now I'm facing other not relevant issues. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-default" id="lookup" />
```

use button

```
<input type="button" value="Find" class="btn btn-default" id="lookup" />
```

One more thing, let's make sure that you are not getting error. Add this to your ajax call

```
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
        strUser = $('#userid').val();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "strUser":"' + strUser + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/findUser",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#results').val(data.servername)
        })
.fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // alert(thrownError + "--" + xhr.responseText);
        var data = xhr.responseText;
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
         alert(jsonResponse['Message']);
 });
```

Comment: That did nothing.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle did you add error handling and do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes and yes, totally separate issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414998/using-runspace-factory-for-powershell-gives-error?noredirect=1#comment81783574_47414998

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be binding form submit event handler rather than `onclick` of a submit button, @rory is right tho you are not returning `false`.

```
<script>
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        strUser = $('#userid').val();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "strUser":"' + strUser + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/findUser",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#results').val(data.servername)
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

you should replace the `$('form')` with your `formId` if there are mutiple forms on your page.

Comment: Yeah this breaks it entirely, it's not a form right now. It's just a test to get one function working. Also not sure what return false; is for. False for what?

Comment: if there is not any form there, why using button type `submit` another thing, the `return false` is an older way to do the `event.preventDefault()` for a form when you are binding the submit event of a form, it just prevents it from submitting to a page specified in the `action` attribute of the form. just like using the submit button type in the form to submit the form with `ajax` rather than page submit.