# Using Runspace Factory for Powershell Gives Error

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm getting the following error on this using line below, I've never seen it up until I started at this new company.

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: ReflectionOnly loading is not supported on this platform.
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadMshSnapinAssembly(PSSnapInInfo mshsnapinInfo)

Error occurs right AT the using statement. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 2008 R2.

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
          runspace.Open();
          PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
          ps.Runspace = runspace;
          PSSnapInException psex;
          runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Citrix*", out psex);

          Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

          Command getSession = new Command("Get-XASession");
          getSession.Parameters.Add("-ComputerName", serverName);
          getSession.Parameters.Add("-AccountDisplayName", objWINS + "\\" + strUser);
          pipeline.Commands.Add(getSession);
          Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: what dll version are you referencing?

Comment: I'm not positive but I think 6.1.7601.17515

Comment: I don't know who marked this down but it's annoying that they didn't say why. I've searched this error on Google and there is VERY little info on it. 4 unrelated results if you put quotes around the error.

Comment: can you provide more code and what do you have in your imports section

Comment: I've added more but really it doesn't even get past the using statement.

Comment: Problem was .NET Core. Doesn't support any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that powershell runspace factory does not support .NET Core applications. I had to recreate my application using the normal .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Comment: you should select it as the correct answer if this worked for you.so others having the same problem also get benefit

Comment: Yeah I know, doesn't let you do that for 24 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this package is newer than your question but the correct answer in 2020 is to stick with dotnet core and use the right package.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
```

Comment: Yeah I'm sure they finally support it now.