# System.Automation.Runspaces Error in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I've tried to run the a piece of code in a Console Application - `C#` (`.NET Framework 4.5` project) and it works. But when I tried to migrate it to `ASP.NET Core 2.0`, the code would return an error(as shown below).

```
    using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

    public void Powershell()
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module AzureAD -Force;");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString " + "\"Accenture01\"" + " -AsPlainText -Force");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (" + "\"TestID01@eso.dev.accenture.com\"" + ", $password)");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADApplication -Filter " + "\"DisplayName eq " + "\'TestApp\'" + "\"");
        var result = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
```

The **error** is

> "'*System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'ReflectionOnly loading is
>   not supported on this platform.*'"

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Runspace Factory for Powershell Gives Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414998/using-runspace-factory-for-powershell-gives-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Powershell.Create()` instead of Pipeline, Invoke the `Import-Module` before you continue, use `Add-Command` instead of `AddScript`

Try this: (after opening the runspace, e.g `runspace.Open();`)

```
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    powershell.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("AzureAD");
    powershell.Invoke();
    powershell.Commands.Clear();
    powershell.AddScript("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString " + "\"Accenture01\"" + " -AsPlainText -Force");
    powershell.AddScript("$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (" + "\"TestID01@eso.dev.accenture.com\"" + ", $password)");
    powershell.AddScript("Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred");
    powershell.AddScript("Get-AzureADApplication -Filter " + "\"DisplayName eq " + "\'TestApp\'" + "\"");
    powershell.Invoke();
    var results = powershell.Invoke();
}
```